# How is using the lens library different than programming in an imperative language?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

What advantages do we get by using the lens library over a language like C or Python?

I get that state is still immutable with the lens library, but from a practical perspective, how is it any different?

Examples would be very useful.

EDIT:

What I really want to know is why having immutable state is advantageous/disadvantageous for the lens library, e.g. can we not achieve better performance with lens with mutable state?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @ErikPhilips That's not really true. `lens` is very unlike imperative programming, except in some minor syntax things. It's not that hard to provide a list of significant differences.

Comment: [This lens tutorial](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html) illustrates several lens features that have no counterparts in imperative languages.

Comment: I'd say that `lens` doesn't make Haskell much like C or Python except in that it now encompasses a few idioms of those languages. The differences remain about as large as the differences between Haskell and C/Python normally... minus a small amount of syntax and plus this whole new concept, the lens, which generalizes getters and setters (quite a lot).

Comment: What I am asking is, if I need to solve a new problem which would be well-suited to be solved statefully, why should I use Haskell with lens instead of a language like Python?

Comment: Though inspired by the requirements of physics simulations, `lens` isn't necessarily about imperative programming or state at all,  though you can certainly use the library to advantage in such situations (see the above-referenced tutorial).  What it gives you is composable, performant, abstract/generic, type-directed ways to operate on interesting data. For instance, you can use also `lens` for [maximally elegant JSON parsing](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/lens-aeson-traversals-prisms) or [writing a compiler](https://github.com/ermine-language/ermine/tree/master/src/Ermine).

Comment: @user3217013 The greatest advantage over Python there is the strong typing of effects (including state). Lens doesn't fundamentally change this, it just allows for code that is more compact, intuitive and reusable.